# Ошибка при создании Telegram-бота

Tags: java, json, telegram-bot, maven

Решил сделать `телеграмм-бота`, но так как опыта создания подобных приложений нет, решил воспользоваться помощью данного источника(код местами не актуален по всей видимости): https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/504-sozdanie-telegram-bota-na-java-ot-idei-do-deploja. При написании первой части возникли ошибки связанные скорее всего с `Singleton`, но я их вроде устранил(в классе `Main` при `.getBot()` выдавало ошибку). При компиляции выдает данную ошибку:

```java
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/guice-4.1.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error executing setWebook method
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:55)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to api.telegram.org:443 [api.telegram.org/149.154.167.220, api.telegram.org/2001:67c:4e8:f004:0:0:0:9] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:43)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 12 more
```

Подумал может с версией проблемы но нет(перепробовал все версии от 8 до 13).
Проект собран на Maven.

На данном этапе он должен всего лишь компилироваться без ошибок.

Файлы и классы проекта:

```java
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try{
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(Bot.getBot());
        }catch (TelegramApiRequestException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import static org.telegram.telegrambots.logging.BotLogger.log;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private static Bot bot;

    public static Bot getBot() {
        if (bot == null) {
            bot = new Bot();
        }
        return bot;
    }

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        String message = update.getMessage().getText();
        sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), message);
    }

    private synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId, String s) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(s);
        try {
            sendMessage(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "TestBot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "947832101:AAFpi9KSrMxNd9qshdbfNJbM7Mp2xQ18Uok";
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>t.me.bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>arovaro_bot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Нашел решение? А то у меня такая же проблема

Comment: На этом источнике все устарело. На хабре нашел более свежий и актуальный вариант - https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/111328/.

Comment: у меня все равно не работает, выдает точно такие же ошибки. А у вас заработало?

Comment: да, заработало.

Comment: тут кстати ответ подоспел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте свежую версию

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Только вот тут надо будет поменять

```
try {
    execute(sendMessage);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
     log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", e.toString());
}
```